# In ASP.NET MVC3, shall I place the checks on my search filter in the controller or service layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, service-layer, search-form

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application in C# and Razor.

In the view `MyView` I have a search filter, where user might select through **radio buttons** (mutually exclusive) whether s/he wants to perform the search based on time period (for instance from 1/2/2012 to 8/3/2012) or by specifying exact date or day, month, year, etc...

Depending on the user's choice I shall call a different set of methods in my **service layer**. For instance if the user select period I call `FindProductsSoldPeriod`, if the user selects a specific month I call `FindProductsSoldMonth`.

The check on which radio button has been selected has to be done in the the controller or in the service layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The check on which radio button has been selected has to be done in
>   the the controller or in the service layer?

In the controller or the View. The service layer doesn't even know what a *radio button* means.

Or to be a bit more precise: a properly designed service layer shouldn't know what a *radio button* means.

Comment: thanks, indeed in the View the check is performed by client side scripting, isn't it?

Comment: @CiccioMiami, yes, could be client side scripting if you need to perform this check as soon as the value of some radio button changes.